# Scope of MPI communicator

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, scope, mpi

I am new to MPI and wanted to play around with it, i.e. the boost wrapper implementation around it. So now I am wondering about "when" MPI exactly starts to work on multiple nodes. I read in the documentation:

> The mpi::environment object is initialized with the program arguments (which it may modify) in your main program. The creation of this object initializes MPI, and its destruction will finalize MPI. In the vast majority of Boost.MPI programs, an instance of mpi::environment will be declared in main at the very beginning of the program.

However what if I want the code to do several things before I initialise MPI (only on the main node), but don't want to have an if-clause around them. Does MPI simply start the same code on several nodes and the communicator just tells the different nodes which process number they have? And then the developer decides via clauses which node does which operations? Or does the multi node environment actually start with the instantiation of MPI and could I do something like this for example:

```
#include <boost/mpi/environment.hpp>
#include <boost/mpi/communicator.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main(int, char**) {
  std::cerr << "I am something on the main process should do." << std::endl;
  {
    boost::mpi::environment env;
    boost::mpi::communicator world;
    std::cerr << "I am process " << world.rank() << " of " << world.size() << "." << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

In my expectation this would not be restricted to boost MPI, since it is just a wrapper around MPI itself.

Comment: Though the MPI standard does not specify what happens before `MPI_Init()` and after `MPI_Finalize()`, most implementations start all the programs when `mpirun` is invoked (which means all tasks execute in parallel the code before `MPI_Init()` and after `MPI_Finalize()`.

Answer (score 1):

MPI is process-based. The mpiexec program makes an ssh connection to each available node, and starts your program as a process there. At least, that's how it's usually done. And this is known as the SPMD: Single Program Multiple Data model. So whatever code you write: the main is executed by every node (core, whatever; really: process) identically. Until you `MPI_Init` and compute the rank, every MPI process does totally the same thing.